# Update huge table based on key in another table

Tags: mysql, updates

I am trying to update a table and set a look up id to 0 for a large amount of records in one table (items) based one whether the id (pk) exists in a second (backup_table) table. The two tables are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `lookupid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `backup_table` (
  `item_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `backup_value` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The items table has about 600M rows, backup_table has about 25M rows.

I started off with a query like this:

```
UPDATE items i
JOIN (SELECT i.id FROM items i
JOIN backup_table bu on i.id = bu.item_id
WHERE i.id != 0
LIMIT 10000) x ON i.id = x.id
SET i.id = 0;
```

I have put this in a php wrapper that will just keep executing this until it's complete. Each iteration takes between 30-200 seconds, with a completion time around 14.5 hours. I need to dramatically speed this up to fit inside my 3 hour maintenance window. Any suggestions on speeding this up would be GREATLY appreciated.

Would an EXIST() be better? How would that look exactly?

Comment: Have you set index on items and backup_table ID field? If yes, you should not join into join.

Comment: Your LIMIT statement is there to limit the query execution time, or you really need to process first 1k results?

Comment: Sorry yes, there is an index on item_id in the backup table. Joining to a Join is the only way I can limit the update statement and not try and run all 25M at once, creating a huge transaction.

Comment: @user3417005 . . . You have declared `items.id` as a primary key.  Then you set a bunch of values to `0`.  Primary keys should be unique.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm confused.  You have declared `items.id` as a primary key, and then you set 10,000 of them to the same value.  This should be returning an error.

Assuming that there is some inconsistency between your query and the table definitions, have you tried this version?

```
UPDATE items i
    SET i.id = 0
    WHERE i.id <> 0 AND
          EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM backup_table bu WHERE i.id = bu.item_id)
    LIMIT 10000;
```

This should save the overhead of creating a derived table.

By the way, using `limit` without an `order by` is suspect, because the rows returned are in an arbitrary order.

Comment: Ugh, it's too early sorry, I am setting the lookup_id = 0 in the items table.... That looks good, I will give that a show and see if it's faster. Thank you.